# Dual Citizen with a Canadian Passport

Tags: passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian currently sitting in a room waiting to take the Oath for American citizenship. They told us we will not be able to enter the US on a foreign passport once we are American citizens. However, my younger sister who has dual citizenship has previously traveled with her Canadian passport to other countries and successfully reentered the US.

Will I need to have an American passport to reenter the US?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The law states that US citizens should always enter the US with their US passport. If you enter the US on a Canadian passport, you will get in trouble only if the immigration official knows you are a US citizen. That might be how your sister managed it. You might get away with it, but it might also involve telling some lies to an immigration official which is never a good idea.

Immigration can't keep a US citizen out of the US, as long as you can prove you are a US citizen.

Comment: Note that this still allows you to travel to other countries and present your Canadian passport there.  I'm a dual citizen as well, and I have flown back & forth to several other countries from the USA, presenting my Canadian passport on arrival to the third country and my US passport on my return to the US.